# Spring Boot says no bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, flyway

I'm working on a new app (to me) and I received the no bean 'entityManagerFactory' available error on startup. Other people who've had this suggest it would not occur had I properly defined the data source. What confuses me is that either Spring Boot/JPA or Flyway (which I'm also using) insists on specific property names being used for your *one* data source. I'm not sure how someone would handle it if you had more than one. I need to change our application.properties file to fetch from environment variables so they can fetch the values from a secret.  I have one definition so that flyway can do it's possible migrations. I have another so that Spring-Boot can do it's JPA based work. I have another because the existing code previously defined a dataSource and gets wired in accordingly. All are going to the same database. I wish I could use only one collection of application.properties properties, but more importantly, I want this entityManagerFactory error resolved. Because my fixes feel like a kludge, I wanted to reach out and see what I'm not understanding.

Here's the application.properties

```
spring.profiles.active=sprint-vault-services-not-available
spring.application.name=file-generator
file.generator.schema=FILE_GENERATOR

spring.flyway.enabled=true
spring.flyway.locations=classpath:db/migration
spring.flyway.schemas=${file.generator.schema}
spring.flyway.baseline-on-migrate=false

file-generator.date-format=MMddyy
file-generator.time-format=HHmmss
file-generator.ebcdic-output-path=app/output/ebcdic
file-generator.csv-output-path=app/output/csv
file-generator.header-timestamp-format=yyyyMMddHHmmss
file-generator.file-sequence-number=1

logging.path=app/logs

bcupload_datasource_url=${BCUPLOAD_DATASOURCE_URL}
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=FILE_GENERATOR
bcupload_datasource_username=${BCUPLOAD_DATASOURCE_USERNAME}
bcupload_datasource_password=${BCUPLOAD_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD}
bcupload_datasource_driver=${BCUPLOAD_DATASOURCE_DRIVER}
bcupload_datasource_flyway_db_name=LocalFileGenerator

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=${BCUPLOAD_DATASOURCE_DRIVER}
spring.datasource.url=${BCUPLOAD_DATASOURCE_URL}
spring.datasource.password=${BCUPLOAD_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD}
spring.datasource.username=${BCUPLOAD_DATASOURCE_USERNAME}
spring.jpa.database-platform=DB2Platform
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none


spring.flyway.url= ${BCUPLOAD_DATASOURCE_URL}
spring.flyway.user=${BCUPLOAD_DATASOURCE_USERNAME}
spring.flyway.password=${BCUPLOAD_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD}


spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC
```

```
2021-04-12 23:06:34 DEBUG o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter - Application failed to start due to an exception
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:814)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1282)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:297)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:691)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:374)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:134)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1444)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:623)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:611)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.onApplicationEvent(DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.java:51)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.onApplicationEvent(DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.java:36)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:403)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:360)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:897)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at com.mycompany.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.FileGeneratorApplication.main(FileGeneratorApplication.java:22)
```

Bean definition of datasource:

```
package com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.ssc.file.generator.configuration;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;

@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {
    private String dataSourceUrl;
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private String driver;
    
    /*
    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder(Environment environment) {
        Map<String, String> jpaProperties = new HashMap<>();
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getProperty("spring.jpa.show-sql"));
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql"));
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect"));
        return new EntityManagerFactoryBuilder(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter(), jpaProperties, null);
    }
    */

    @Autowired
    public DataSourceConfig(@Value("${bcupload_datasource_url}") String bcupload_datasource_url,
            @Value("${bcupload_datasource_username}") String bcupload_datasource_username,
            @Value("${bcupload_datasource_password}") String bcupload_datasource_password,
            @Value("${bcupload_datasource_driver}") String bcupload_datasource_driver) {
        this.dataSourceUrl = bcupload_datasource_url;
        this.userName = bcupload_datasource_username;
        this.password = bcupload_datasource_password;
        this.driver = bcupload_datasource_driver;
    }

    @Bean(name = "bcUploadDataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                .url(dataSourceUrl)
                .username(userName)
                .password(password)
                .driverClassName(driver).build();

    }

}
```

Comment: I think, since you have different bean name `bcUploadDataSource` than spring boot may have expected, it could not create the other beans for database to work, can you check the logs for more warning and error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a project with several datasources and each datasource end up looking something like this:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.HashMap;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = {"com.your.repositories.packages"},
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager")
public class DataSourceConfig{


    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.entity.pacakges"});
        em.setPersistenceUnitName("your_name");
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto"));
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show-sql", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.show-sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults",
                env.getProperty("spring.jpa.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults." + NAME));

        properties.put("hibernate.physical_naming_strategy", SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy.class.getName());
        properties.put("hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy", SpringImplicitNamingStrategy.class.getName());

        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

        return em;
    }

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManager().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

So for your error, probably try to use LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean instead of EntityManagerFactoryBuilder

Comment: env.getProperty("spring.jpa.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults."+NAME.  Would NAME be a database name? I think you alluded to having multiple DataSourceConfig's for each datasource, but I didn't fully understand how that would get implemented. Thx for your efforts btw. I really appreciate the time you spent crafting the response.

Comment: Hey, yes sorry NAME was just a variable I removed to simplify the answer but forgot to remove it here, in our case for exqample it's just a string named "PROD".

Comment: So yes, basically you create a similar class for every datasource you have. Then based on what you provided as parameters for the @EnableJpaRepositories annotation the repositories in this package will automatically use this datasource. Let me know if that makes sense to you.

Comment: Say I had two datasources, both with a JDBC URL, a username string, a password string all in a system environment variable. Would I specify pass those env values in at the dataSource() method above? I've been burned in the past by not having a spring.datasource property. I'm not sure how to tell Spring-Boot/JPA/Hikari that I have not just one datasource, so don't be looking in spring.datasource. Let me tell you where to look.